# Subset multiple row values into new table and and count string pattren occurences

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following table for processing (Table1):

```
Fuse    Ident   Grade
A1  BLU123  skyline
A1  RED235  blue
A1  RED345  ortho
B1  RED160  linx
B1  BLU760  milli
B2  BLU222  moli
B2  RED201  straw
C1  RED201  straw
C2  BLU222  moli
D1  RED235  blue
D1  BLU123  skyline
E1  NA  NA  NA
E2  NA  NA  NA
F1  BLU999  monte
F1  BLU23  nome
```

I'm trying to process the above table to obtain a final table (Table 2) as follows:

Option1:

```
Grade1  Grade2  row#
blue    skyline 2
ortho   skyline 1
linx    milli   1
straw    moli   2
```

Option 2:

```
Grade1  Grade2  row#
blue;ortho  skyline 1
linx    milli   1
straw   moli    2
```

The following table explains how to arrive at the final tables above:

```
RED BLU Grade1  Grade2
RED235  BLU123  blue    skyline
RED345  BLU123  ortho   skyline
RED160  BLU760  linx    milli
RED201  BLU222  blue    skyline
```

Column "Fuse" in Table 1 has multiple entries for a particular value (e.g., A1). Within the "A1" table subset for column "Fuse", the corresponding "Ident" column must have at least an entring starting with "BLU" and "RED" to make a complete set for recording values for Grade1 and Grade2 columns. Two complete sets can be derived from "A1" subset (RED235,BLU123; RED345   BLU123). Finally as in Table 2, numbers of occurences of combined Grade 1 and Grade2 columns are recorded. Other conditions are: empty rows for columns "Fuse" and "Ident" are ignored, and when there are no complementary sets of strings starting with "BLU" and "RED" in column "Ident", the rows are ingores

Here's my attempt:

```
grp=df.groupby(["Fuse","Ident"])
[grp.get_group(x) for x in grp.groups]
```

My code did not work. Can someone help with a better code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### count the aggregated occurrences

```
out = (df
         # extract BLU/RED as col (other methods are possible)
 .assign(group=df['Ident'].str[:3])
 .groupby(['Fuse', 'group'])['Grade'].agg(';'.join) # aggregate multiple occurrences
 .unstack().value_counts()  # count values
 .reset_index(name='count')
)
```

output:

```
       BLU         RED  count
0    milli        linx      1
1     moli       straw      1
2  skyline        blue      1
3  skyline  blue;ortho      1
```

###### older answer

You can use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as main step:

```
out = (df
         # extract BLU/RED as col (other methods are possible)
 .assign(col=df['Ident'].str[:3],
         # get position of each BLU/RED per group
         idx=lambda d: d.groupby(['Fuse', 'col']).cumcount()
        )
 .pivot(index=['Fuse', 'idx'], columns='col') # pivot using new columns
 .dropna(how='all', axis=1) # drop empty columns
 .dropna(how='any', axis=0) # drop rows with missing values
 .droplevel('idx')          # drop intermediate level
)
```

output:

```
       Ident            Grade       
col      BLU     RED      BLU    RED
Fuse                                
A1    BLU123  RED235  skyline   blue
B1    BLU760  RED160    milli   linx
B2    BLU222  RED201     moli  straw
D1    BLU123  RED235  skyline   blue
```

Then you can count the values:

```
out['Grade'].value_counts()
```

output:

```
BLU      RED  
skyline  blue     2
milli    linx     1
moli     straw    1
```

Comment: thanks so much for your help! Apologies for not getting back before now. Your solution is almost perfect except that it outputs  [moli     straw    1] instead of [ortho   skyline 1].

Comment: so a single row can be reused? Then why aren't there 5 combinations in the output (2 for A1, 1 each for B1,B2,D1)?

Comment: Well spotted! I forgot to add the other outputs. I have amended the required outputs accordingly.

Comment: please let me know if further explanation is required.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering what would happen if there was another `BLU456` in `A1` (so 2 BLU, 2 RED)? Would there be 4 combinations for `A1`?

Comment: Yes, there would be 4 combinations, and the number of combinations could grow if some subsets have more than "2BLU,2 RED", and it could get quite complex. If my guess is correct, then option 2 output (see above) may be better for me. Thanks

Comment: @RobJohn the option 2 is easy, see update. Option 1 is possible but would require more computations

Comment: Great! @mozway I agree. There is a little issue - straw, moli occurs at B1/B2 and C1/C2 and row# should be "2"  instead of "1".

Comment: @Rob I'm sorry but I feel that the logic keeps changing… is is normal not to count the C1/C2 as there are not in the same subset. (You said "*Within the "A1" table subset*", not "*across the "A" subsets*"). If you want to group across subgroup, first generate a column of the exact groups you want, then use my code with that instead of "Fuse"

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not explain well initially that the rows where the same combinations in Grade1 and Grade2 occur must be totalled.

Comment: @Rob I got that part, but how do you match the BLU/RED? I understood within a Fuse (i.e. A1 with A1 but not A1 with A2), or is it rather within all As, Bs, Cs?

Comment: The idea is that (1) within any subset ("A1" or  "B1" or "B2" etc), matching is done for BLU/RED, then (2) for all subsets together, the rows where the same combinations occur must be totalled - that is all rows of combinations from all As,Bs,Cs are searched and similar combinations are totalled. Please let me know if I'm still not making sense.

Comment: I have the feeling there is something off with the logic (I might be wrong), but to me the combinations of the different rules shouldn't give this output. Anyway I gave you quite some hints on how to proceed, why don't you try to adapt it with your logic in mind and then complete the question with what you're eventually stuck with?

Comment: I decided to think about the solution in a different way and feel that your solumn is suffiecient for now. I really appreciate your help and discussions.